# How to add shortcut for 'Only Render'?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, customization, shortcut

How can I add a shortcut for the 'Only Render' checkbox in the Display section of the Properties pane?
I use the function a lot to get a better view on things and would save time if there was a shortcut for it.

Comment: As an aside, the [Amaranth Toolset](http://pablovazquez.org/amaranth/) addon adds a *ton* of useful things, including a shortcut to show only render.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > Input*, navigate to *3D view > 3D view (Global)*, then scroll to the bottom of *3D view > (Global)* and click *add new*.

1. Put [`wm.context_toggle`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.ops.wm.html?#bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle) as the operator.

   This is an operator which toggles a property given by a datapath parameter.
2. Put `space_data.show_only_render` as the datapath parameter (you can put stuff there even if it appears grayed out). You can get the datapath for any checkbox by right clicking on it and selecting *Copy Data Path*. The datapath can then be pasted with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
3. Assign a key combination which doesn't conflict with an existing shortcut (e.g. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>)

[image]

Now pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> (or whatever you assigned as the shortcut) in the 3D view will toggle *show only render*.

Comment: What is this: ⎈ symbol... and why is it next to the ctrl key... Is it a windows thing? I know on mac these: http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/mac-keyboard-symbols.jpg are the notations for each symbol

Comment: @10Replies because it's the [ISO keyboard symbol for 'control'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key)

Comment: Hmmm, strange that I have never encountered it before. I use (and troubleshoot) with windows all the time.

Comment: @10Replies Perhaps since it seems relativly few keyboards actually have it on their ctrl keys.. Mine is one of the few I've observed it on, or at least it has something that resembles it.