# Is there a shortcut to repeat the last operation in Blender

Tags: shortcut

I'm currently doing a lot of UV mapping work and I find myself repeating the same long shortcuts over and over. For example, aligning the selected uvs in y can be done by pressing s, y, 0 (scale y to 0) then enter to confirm. Since I'm doing this over and over again, I was wondering if there is a Blender shortcut to repeat the last operation, similar to the repeat key ('g') in Maya.

By the way, I know there is actually an align function, but even that requires a couple of of key presses and it's another shortcut to remember, where I find scaling to 0 more intuitive, so repeat is what I'm after here.

Comment: by the way there is way to do all this work by 1 click using the UV squares addon.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Yes.**

<kbd>F3</kbd> will give you a list of recent actions. After selecting one action from the list, the next time you press <kbd>F3</kbd> the list will be positioned with the same action under the cursor. This makes it very easy to call the same action over and over quickly by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> (without having to move the mouse), or <kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.

In the 3D view you can call the previous action with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, however this doesn't seem to work in the UV editor.

---

Another option is to add a custom shortcut for the align operators.

To do this add a new shortcut in <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > Input*. You probably want to define it in some reasonable context like *Image > UV editor*, so expand the corresponding sections and click *New shortcut* at the bottom of the *UV editor* section.

Then put `uv.align` as the operator and assign a key combination:

[image]

Note that you also have the option to change the various parameter the operator is called with when the shortcut is pressed (though in this case there is only one parameter):

[image]

*Even if the drop down appears grayed out, you can probably still change it. It will appeared grayed out if no parameter is specified, in which case the default it used.*

Also see: [How to add shortcut for 'Only Render'?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17822/599)

Comment: That works well. Thanks! As a side note, since I use a tablet, it's sometimes hard to keep the cursor in the same position, so hitting enter instead of LMB works better.

Comment: @MrFlamey Ah, yes. I don't have a tablet (unfortunately), so using the mouse is faster for me (I usually keep one hand on the keyboard and one on the mouse). I added it to the answer :)

Comment: How about on a Mac? F3 brings up Mission Control in MacOS.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> one or more actions from the Info Panel (grow it vertically a bit) and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> them at once into the Python-Console. This executes choosen actions done in the past.
You can also manage them as recorded script blocks in any editor of you choice even the Blender internal text-editor.

Comment: This is hugely helpful for repeating a large sequence of actions on different primitives. That's awesome

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible to press Shift R in some modes to repeat the last operation like grab, or add a face. But this only replys the last action and only one, so select and align wont be possible, but extrude and move it on unit would work when it's done once. (Not Extrude and grab)

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. Perfect for deleting keyframes in the timeline