# Assign shortcuts to different values from thedrop-down menu "Merge"

Tags: customization, shortcut, operator

I want to assign a separate hotkey to "At Last" or "Collapse"
Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: You may do it in the same manner as I've shown here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-mesh-selection-mode

Comment: This method uses the assigned hotkey to the whole menu "Merge"
I want  to assigned hot key work on a certain option from this menu

Comment: Yup, you're right. I haven't thought about it. I'll try to find another solution.

Comment: One way probably would be pretty much the same as here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/how-to-not-extend-selection-with-box-select but for Merge. Find it in User Prefs, choose in options which method and that's it. The downside is that you'll have to setup new shortcut to achieve other menu options.

Answer (score 2):

To make merging vertices faster change in User Preferences setup for this shortcut enabling *Type* option just below the main options:

[image: screenshot of user prefs to change]

Select the desired type from the list  to make this shortcut execute command with given option and skip any dialogs (most likely you will want to create also shortcuts to use other options of the operator).
To disable that either restore settings or press on X button near the *Type* selector. Read more details on this technique in this post - [How To NOT extend selection with Box Select?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/how-to-not-extend-selection-with-box-select).

---

However you have other approaches available too without need to change shortcuts.

One approach would be to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the last action. So you would select 3 vertices in desired order, choose needed option from menu and then after selecting next verts just execute *Repeat Last*.

Anotehr way would be using list of Undo history from <kbd>F3</kbd>. Once doing any action it will be accessible from that list and you will be able to repeat it by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>. See more here - [Is there a shortcut to repeat the last operation in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/is-there-a-shortcut-to-repeat-the-last-operation-in-blender).

Also you could just choose another way of modeling and dissolve those vertices either with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* or *Dissolve Edges* (make sure to select needed geometry first).