# Remap spacebar to last action/command?

Tags: shortcut

Coming from an Autocad layout, it's so convenient to repeat the last command/action by hitting the spacebar, anyway to do that in Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/is-there-a-shortcut-to-repeat-the-last-operation-in-blender (I don't know if you can remap it to the space bar or not, but this might be helpful anyways).

Answer (score 1):

Repeat Last (**Shift+R**) should do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try deleting the space bar's default "play animation" setting and then try doing it.